# function in input type=file in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

how to write a function in `input type =file` in php.Html code without `echo statemen`t is working well as copying the path to textbox.

```
  <form name="profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <?php
      echo '<p style="margin-left:1cm"><input type="text" id="file2" size=18 maxlength=500><input type="file" name="bfile2" onchange="CopyMe(this, 'file2');" /></p>';
   ?>
 </form>

 <script>
function CopyMe(oFileInput, sTargetID) {
   document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = oFileInput.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems lies in this section:

```
CopyMe(this, 'file2');
```

The `'` character is breaking your echo.
Escape the characters with `\`.

So your code ends up as:

```
echo '<p style="margin-left:1cm"><input type="text" id="file2" size=18 maxlength=500><input type="file" name="bfile2" onchange="CopyMe(this, \'file2\');" /></p>';
```